# fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/bluez/' not found

Tags: git, repo

I had a problem downloading the source code in Ubuntu 14.04 environment. How do I solve this problem? The download is progressing, but I posted a question because I was nervous. If you can download it manually, please let me know how.

```
~$ cd ~
~$ mkdir myandroid bin
~$ curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
~$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
~$ cd myandroid
~$ ~/bin/repo init -u https://github.com/UDOOboard/android_udoo_platform_manifest -b android-6.0.1
~$ ~/bin/repo sync -j5
```

Output from the console.

```
Fetching:  5% (20/388) platform/external/apache-http
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/bluez/' not found
platform/external/bluetooth/bluez:
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/bluez/' not found
platform/external/bluetooth/bluez: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/bluez/' not found
platform/external/bluetooth/bluez:
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/bluez/' not found
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/bluetooth/bluez from git://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/bluez
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/glib/' not found
platform/external/bluetooth/glib:
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/glib/' not found
platform/external/bluetooth/glib: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/glib/' not found
platform/external/bluetooth/glib:
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/glib/' not found
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/bluetooth/glib from git://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/glib
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/sbc/' not found
platform/external/bluetooth/sbc:
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/sbc/' not found
platform/external/bluetooth/sbc: sleeping 4.0 seconds before retrying
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/sbc/' not found
platform/external/bluetooth/sbc:
fatal: repository 'https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/sbc/' not found
error: Cannot fetch platform/external/bluetooth/sbc from git://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/sbc
```

Comment: Plugging `https://git.osdn.jp/gitroot/android-x86/platform/external/bluetooth/bluez/` into a browser tells me that there is nothing at that web site. There's nothing *Git* can do about that: either the web site serves up data to the public, or it does not. If it's a *private* site that requires a password or equivalent, you'll need the password or equivalent.

Comment: @torek  The file is located on a similar path, so should I download it separately and combine it?

Comment: I have no idea. I was just noting that the original project seems to list unavailable repositories. It (the original project) is probably out of date or abandoned; it's probably worth trying to contact whoever owns it, or otherwise researching its status.

Comment: Is there a way to download directly instead of 'repo sync'?

Comment: I have no idea: that's not a question about Git, that's a question about Google's `repo` program. I added the [tag:repo] tag.